# Mock.Object returns null

Tags: c#, .net, moq

Given the following mock creations

```
_mockSlaTimer = new Mock<IMPulse>();
_mockDataService = new Mock<IDataService>();
_mockDialogService = new Mock<IDialogService>();
_mockViewLocator = new Mock<IViewLocator<IPage>>();
_mockInsightsProvider = new Mock<IInsightService>();
_mockNavigationService = new Mock<INavigationService>();
```

`_mockViewLocator.Object` property it is always `null`

The interface definitions are nothing fancy:

```
public interface IPage
{
}

public interface IViewLocator<TPageType> where TPageType : IPage
{
    void RegisterViewFor<TViewModelType>(TPageType page) where TViewModelType : IViewModel;
    TPageType ResolveViewFor<TViewModelType>() where TViewModelType : IViewModel;
}
```

Note the screen grab below

[image]

Why would the object property return null?

Comment: don't you need to mock the IPage too?

Comment: Important detail: `_mockViewLocator.Object` is not null - it throws a `System.ArgumentNullException` when accessed. Do you have any more details on that?

Comment: I tried your code without issue, I could even access to _mockViewLocator.Object, so more details are needed here in order to figure out whats happening.

Comment: @afonte the tests used to run and pass. I updated moq just to make sure I'm not referencing a possible breaking change in the API - I'll check tomorrow again (midnight here) #peace

Comment: Do you put any `.Setup(...)` or similar on the mock instance `_mockViewLocator`? The interface `IViewLocator<>` is generic, and its two methods `RegisterViewFor<>` and `ResolveViewFor<>` are generic as well. Your question does not show how you use the methods.